# Are the standard natural numbers an outstanding model of PA?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

Is the model $\mathcal N$ of the *standard natural numbers* in any way outstanding from all the possible (non-standard) models of PA? For example, might it be that $\mathcal N$ is some kind of a minimal model, i.e. it is contained in every other model in some useful sense?

I am not very familiar with the terminology here. I heard about elementary submodels, prime models, atomic models, ... . I heard that every interpretation of ZFC has its *unique natural numbers*, hence it seems there is a way to distinguish $\mathcal N$ in there. Answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209910/embdedding-standard-models-of-pa-into-nonstandard-models) seem to imply that there is an embedding of $\mathcal N$ into each non-standard model.

Comment: Yes, it is minimal in the sense that it is contained in every model. In every model it's the subset obtained by repeatedly applying successor to zero.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok, yes, it is already a subset of any other model by cardinality. I guess your construction of the embedding is also somehow structure preserving. Is there some terminology for this? Also, is this a unique thing for $\mathcal N$? There are other countable models.

Comment: I'd probably wouldn't be able to help you with this question, but it would be nice if you explained the alphabet soup. What is PA? What is ZFC? Zone Free Classification?

Comment: @Lisa [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) is the standard set-theoretic foundation for  mathematics. [PA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) is Peano arithmetic. When writing a question using the logic tag, it is totally reasonable to assume all readers are familiar with these acronyms.

Comment: @Alex Oh yeah, the Zermelo Frankel C-something. I came to this question by the elementary number theory tag, though.

Comment: @Lisa I am sorry if this tag misguided you! I probably chose some alias tag and not specifically elementary number theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on Qiaochu's comment, the standard model $\mathbb{N}$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) minimal model of PA in the sense of embeddings. Namely, the following is true:

- $\mathbb{N}$ embeds uniquely into every model of PA. Moreover, if $\mathcal{M}$ is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{N}$, then the embedding of $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathcal{M}$ is elementary.
- If $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of PA not isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, then $\mathcal{M}$ does *not* embed into $\mathbb{N}$.

Each of these facts is a straightforward exercise in model theory - the key point being that $\mathbb{N}$ is characterized uniquely amongst models of PA (up to isomorphism) by the *second-order* principle of induction. Besides giving another characterization of $\mathbb{N}$ (phrased differently: $\mathbb{N}$ is the only well-ordered model of PA), second-order induction lets us reason, well, inductively when comparing arbitrary models of PA with $\mathbb{N}$. For instance, if $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of PA, we build an embedding $f_\mathcal{M}: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$ by induction as:

- $f_\mathcal{M}(0)=0^\mathcal{M}$, and
- having defined $f_\mathcal{M}(n)$, we let $f_\mathcal{M}(n+1)=f_\mathcal{M}(n)+^\mathcal{M}1^\mathcal{M}$.

By the second-order induction principle for $\mathbb{N}$, this does in fact define a map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{M}$, and it's not hard to show that this map is an embedding.

Note, by the way, that PA is overkill here: we may replace it by the theory of the natural numbers with successor. This theory, in contrast to PA, is complete and decidable!

---

Another very different characterization of $\mathbb{N}$ is via computability: the standard model of PA is the only countable model of PA with a *computable presentation*, by [Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem). This is a more involved result. In particular, while PA is still overkill, there are theories of arithmetic much stronger than arithmetic with successor which are *too weak* for the Tennenbaum phenomenon to hold for them.