# Definition of the natural numbers, integers, rational and irrational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, foundations

I know that :

> The natural numbers are the elements of a set $\mathbb{N}$, with a distinguished element $1$
>   (one) and map $S : \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{N},$ such that :
>
> **N1:** $S$ is injective, i.e. if $m, n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ and $m \neq n$, then $S(m) \neq S(n)$;
>
> **(N2):** $1\notin S(\mathbb{N})$;
>
> **(N3):** if $M ⊆ \mathbb{N}$, $1 ∈ M$ and $S(M) ⊆ M$, then $M = \mathbb{N}$.

But Now :

How defined $ 2,3,4,...$?

And:

How defined $ \mathbb{Z}=\{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\}$?

How defined Rational Numbers?

How defined Real Numbers?

How defined Irrational number?

Comment: Do you mean *real* numbers?

Comment: Note:  "injective" does not mean what you say (you are just writing out a standard property of functions).  Injective means, in this case, that $S(m)=S(n)\implies m=n$.

Comment: There are lots of textbooks about that, and it will be hard to cram their contents into an answer. For a start: what about $2=S(1), 3=S(2), 4=S(3),\ldots$?

Comment: @lulu. it's true . I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no short answer. So let me step over it:

---

**Natural numbers $\Bbb N$**

I personally prefer defining the natural numbers starting with $0$. Your axioms for the natural numbers are essentially the same when doing so, but the further will get easier. The other *natural numbers besides* $0$ are usually defines via the repeated use of $S$ on $0$, like this:

$$1:=S(0),\quad 2:=S(S(0)),\quad 3:=S(S(S(0))),\quad ...$$

**The Integers $\Bbb Z$**

For the *integers*, you consider pairs $(a,b)$ of natural numbers $a,b\in \Bbb N$. You define the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim(a',b')$ for $a+b'=b+a'$. An equivalence class $[(a,b)]$ of such pairs is an integer. For example

$$n:=[(n,0)],\qquad -n:=[(0,n)],\qquad\text{for }n\in\Bbb N.$$

**The Rational numbers $\Bbb Q$**

The *rationals* are also defined via an equivalence class on pairs. This time you take the pair $(a,b),a\in\Bbb Z,b\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ and the relation $(a,b)\sim(a',b')$ iff $ab'=a'b$. You than have

$$\frac ab:=[(a,b)].$$

**The Real numbers $\Bbb R$**

The *reals* can be defined via equivalence classes of [Cauchy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) of rational numbers. Two such sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ are equivalent iff $x_n-y_n\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$. A real number is then an equivalence class $[x_n]$. Any rational number $q$ corresponds to the constant sequence $q,q,q,q,...$. Another example: an irrational number cannot be represented as a constant sequence of rationals, so you have to choose a convergent one like this

$$\pi:=[3,\;3.1,\;3.14,\;3.141,\;3.1415,\;...].$$

---

And we have not even talked about how to define the usual operations $+,-,\times,\div$ on these sets. This is the real hard work.

But for more details you should *really* consider reading a book on the topic because there is never enough space in an Math.SE answer box to explain it here in all details.

Comment: So . you say : The natural numbers are the elements of a set $\mathbb{N}$, with a distinguished element $0$ with :
$N1,N2,N3$ .it's true ?

Comment: @Almot1960 Somehow, Yes. The naturals are the "smallest" model of the [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) (similar to the axioms you gave above). Consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2251117/415941) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2257984/415941) question of mine for further reading.