# Clarifying "$\omega$-models" of ZF(C)

Tags: set-theory

Preliminaries: To be extra clear, I'm assuming (hopefully correctly) the following:

- The "finite von Neumann ordinals" always means the sets $\emptyset , \;\; \{\emptyset\} , \;\; \{\emptyset , \{\emptyset\}\} , \;\; \{ \emptyset , \{\emptyset\} , \{\emptyset , \{\emptyset\}\}\} \ldots \;$ In other words: $\emptyset , \; S(\emptyset), \; S(S(\emptyset)), \; S(S(S(\emptyset))) \ldots$, where $S$ is the successor function $S(x) := x \cup \{x\}$
- The Axiom of Infinity always guarantees the existence of an inductive set, i.e. a set $I$ such that $\emptyset \in I$ and $x \in I \implies (x \cup \{x\}) \in I$

My question is what exactly is meant by an "$\omega$-model" or "$\omega$-standard model"? What I *think* I can infer (with less than 100% confidence) from what I've read is:

- An "$\omega$-model", or "$\omega$-standard model", is a model in which there exists a "smallest" inductive set (the "$\omega$ of the model") whose elements are *exactly* the finite von Neumann ordinals (all the finite von Neumann ordinals but nothing else). That is, the $\omega$ of the model is the "standard" $\omega$.
- Thus also a ***non***-$\omega$-model is a model in which every inductive set contains some other elements in addition to the finite von Neumann ordinals. So for such a model, the "smallest" inductive set is some "non-standard $\omega$".

Is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The finite ordinals aren't defined as in your first bullet because that's not a definition, and even if you try to make it into one, it is circular. There are lots of different ways one can define it... one nice way that doesn't use the axiom of infinity is that a finite ordinal is an ordinal (i.e. a transitive set that is well-ordered by the $\in$ relation) whose reverse ordering is a also well-order. But more often, we take the axiom of infinity for granted and just define a finite ordinal as a member of $\omega$, where $\omega$ is defined as the minimal inductive set, or perhaps as the least limit ordinal. Since here we're concerned mostly with what the set of natural numbers is, as opposed to what a natural number is, let's just take a typical route and define $\omega$ as the minimal inductive set and define a natural number to be any element of $\omega.$

This is a definition in ZF, so any model $(M,E)$ of ZF, there is a set $\omega^M\in M$ such that $(M,E)\models \mbox{"$\omega^M$ is the minimal inductive set."}$ Moreover, $(M,E)\models \mbox{"$E$ is a well-ordering on $\omega^M$"},$ since it's provable in ZF that $\in$ is a well-ordering on $\omega.$ $(M,E)$ is an omega-model if and only if any of the following equivalent statements hold

1. $E$ actually is a well-ordering on the set of $E$-elements of $\omega^M.$
2. The relation $E$ on the set of $E$-elements of $\omega^M$ is isomorphic to $(\omega,\in).$
3. The $E$-elements of $\omega^M$ are exactly $\{(S^M)^n0^M : n\in \omega\},$ where $0^M$ is $(M,E)$'s empty set and $S^M$ $(M,E)$'s ordinal successor function. The sets of the form $(S^M)^n0^M$ are called the model's standard natural numbers.

What happens in a non-omega model is that the model's standard natural numbers are followed by a bunch of other things the model thinks are natural numbers, and they are ordered like a bunch of copies of $\mathbb Z.$ As you indicate in your last bullet, the model still satisfies that $\omega^M$ is the minimal inductive set... it's just simply the case that all of the model's inductive sets contain more than just the model's standard naturals (if you "read the fine print", there's no guarantee otherwise).

On a side note, I say "the model's standard naturals", but one should realize that unlike everything else I attribute to the model, this is not something we can define within the model... it is an external definition. And this has to be the case, since otherwise, we could just use this as the definition of the natural numbers and every model would be an $\omega$-model.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. A couple follow-ups, just to be extra sure I got what you meant: 1) In your definition #3, the superscript $n$ in $(S^M)^n$ is intended to be a [***standard*** natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2258788) (of the "standard model" of Peano arithmetic), correct?  2) By my reading, definition #1 *seems* redundant, i.e. a repetition of the earlier statement that $(M, E) \models$ "$E$ is a well-ordering on $\omega^M$". I presume there's some distinction that I'm missing?

Comment: Also, would you happen to know of a book (or lecture notes or something) that discusses this topic in more detail? Introductory set theory books don't get into this; I looked at the Jech classic *Set Theory* and didn't see anything there either (though admittedly it's a big book, I might have missed something).

Comment: 1) It's intended as an external natural number, not something defined in $M$. In other words, get the element by applying the model's successor function to the model's $0$ $n$ times. 2) Yes you're missing something crucial. Just because it's true in the model that $E$ is a well-ordering doesn't mean it is actually a well ordering externally. It could have infinite descending chains that the model does not see. 3) I don't know a great reference offhand... if you look in Kunen's 1980 book they're defined and discussed briefly in Ch IV section 10.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you mean the correct thing, but you need to be a bit careful with this.

Given a model $\mathcal M=(M,E)$ of ZF(C), we always have $\mathcal M\models"\omega\text{ exists and it contains exactly the finite ordinals}"$ (where $\omega$ is defined as the intersection of all inductive sets), the problem is that we may have $x\in M$ such that  $"x\text{ is a finite ordinal}"$ but $\mathcal M\not\models"x\text{ is a finite ordinal}"$ or maybe $"x\text{ is not a finite ordinal}"$ but $\mathcal M\models"x\text{ is a finite ordinal}"$.

Additionally, we may even have $x\notin M$ such that $"x \text{ is finite ordinal}"$, so $\cal M$ doesn't even know $x$ exists.

Lastly you can have a weird situation where $"x,y \text{ is finite ordinal and }x<y"$ but $\mathcal M\models "x,y \text{ is finite ordinal and }x>y"$

A model if **not** an $\omega$-model if one of the above is true for your model.

$\mathcal N=(N,E)$ is an $\omega$-model exactly when the above doesn't happen, that is, the $\omega$ of $\mathcal N$ is the real $\omega$, and the finite ordinals of $\mathcal N$  are exactly the real finite ordinals and they are ordered like the real finite ordinals.

Comment: Being an $\omega$-model has nothing to do with whether or not the model's natural numbers literally are the natural numbers. It's whether the model's natural numbers are order-isomorphic to the natural numbers.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I rarely saw people use your definition to define an omega model. Even if you take you definition, saying "Being an $ω$-model has nothing to do with whether or not the model's natural numbers literally are the natural numbers" is a bad faith argument, a model is an $ω$-model with your definition if and only if it is isomorphic to one with my definition

Comment: Thanks. BTW, would you happen to know of a book (or lecture notes or something) that discusses this topic in more detail? Introductory set theory books don't get into this; I looked at the Jech classic *Set Theory* and didn't see anything there either (though admittedly it's a big book, I might have missed something).

Comment: @ℋolo Apologies, I wasn't aware that the 'literal' definition was common and I read your answer as focusing on minutae of the real natural numbers being in the model at the expense of what's going on structurally. Now reading the Q/A again I see your intention was probably to make sure OP understand some caveats that go along with their second to last bullet (i.e. actually trying to emphasize a structural understanding of the situation).